# Can Driverless AI instance utilize K80 GPU for faster performance in GCP?

Tags: driverless-ai

I am experimenting with the performance of running experiments on H2o Driverless AI instance on GCP. I have attached a K80 GPU to the instance but when I run the experiments selecting "GPU enabled" , it doesn't appear to be utilizing GPUs. Are there any installation steps that are needed so that the H2o software can begin to utilize this GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the GCP marketplace offering directly:

http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/google-cloud-platform.html

Or install the required nvidia drivers manually yourself.

Comment: I added the GPU to my intsance but it's not utilizing the GPU for running experiments. Is there any special configuration for H2o to use GPU other than clicking on enable GPU when running the experiment?